# Partial gridview in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I am working with Gridview and one of columns takes long time load and makes the whole page to load slowly.  I want to know if there is a way I can show everything (other controls and partial gridview) first except for the slow column, and load the gridview(or the column) later as soon as the data for the column is available.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use AJAX to load your slow grid. Imagine the following:

1. Put your grid in a partial view (if you're using ASP MVC) or in a control if you're using traditional ASP
2. Your page loads, and you show an animated gif in a  saying: "Loading grid..."
3. You make an AJAX request to load the partial view or the control (get the HTML contents)
4. When the request is finished, you replace the content of your gridplaceholder with your real grid content.

Some resources:

- [JQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [Using JQuery with ASP.NET](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=231&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Hope it helps